# Telerik Asp mvc NumericText Validation jQuery Culture Pb

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, jquery-validate, cultureinfo, telerik-mvc

I am using Telerik for asp mvc and I used the Html.Telerik().NumericTextBoxFor

```
@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().Globalization(true).DefaultGroup(group => group.Combined(true).Compress(true)))
@(Html.Telerik().NumericTextBoxFor(loc => loc.LatitudeValue).MinValue(0).MaxValue(90).Spinners(false).InputHtmlAttributes(new { width = "120", style = "width: 120px" }))
```

When the navigator is in English it works, but when I switch to French the separator became "," which is great, but when I write for example 12,45 . jQuery removes the ,45 and puts ,00

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ScriptRegistrar should be *after* the numeric textbox. The [globalization online example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/numerictextbox/globalization?culture=fr-FR) works as expected for me.

Comment: I found The response I downloaded the new version of telerik and Jquery 1.6 and it fixed the pb , You can find the this pb exists for a lot of dev in Telerik forums